# How do I hide some fields to registered users?

Tags: entities, commerce

This is my use case:

- If an **anonymous user** completes an order, the order shows profile type A. When user completes that order, the system creates a new user, and fulfill his profile with the profile2 type A order information.
- If a **registered user** completes an order, it does not show any profile2 information.

I want to make my checkout process shorter for already registered users, and I want for the anonymous users to have a profile filled with the order information.
I get the first part of the use case working (the anonymous user workflow) with the excellent [Commerce Order Profile2 Checkout Panes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_p2cp) module, but I have no idea on what to do to avoid it appears for registered users. The problem is that the fiels in question are profile fields, so I need to grant registered users permission to view/edit them, and I can't hide them there with field permissions or CSS styles because they wouldn't be available to anonymous users too.

What could I do?

Comment: Why it has been voted negatively?

Comment: I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't used profile2 for any commerce site, but the mechanism behind the checkout process for asking profile info for anonymous user is to create account for him on site.
If some information in the profile is mandatory then it will be asked on the time of checkout..& register user won't get those fields at time of checkout.

I use address-field for collecting address for shipping as well as billing, which always keep the old address and its possible to make some address default...so that registered user doesn't find it irritating..

If you must have to use profile2 field then please check whether its required field & if it is...then why some registered users profile is not filled with those information...